# DOMContentLoaded event is not firing

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I have a page with javascript.

In `$(function() {});` Everything works fine except for a couple clients with  web-proxy, it doesn't work.
Digging into the problem, I found that `DOMContentLoaded` event is not firing at those clients (Google Chrome).
 
Is there way to find out reason which prevents firing of event, or getting pending event list ?

Also is there a way to listen to any events which fire before DOMContentLoaded ?

Comment: Can you add complete code here

Comment: Well, it is very simple.

`console.log('Script is working');
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log('DOM Loaded');
});`

Comment: I assume you are doing this because you are binding events?

Comment: Can you check if `window.onload` works?

Comment: @Tushar, got the same. Both events are fired for me and other users, except those clients.